# We need a tag for all the "can I re-encode my video without losing quality" questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-request

Every second question on VP seems to end in the phrase "… without losing quality", because losing any quality will totally kill you when you have some AVCHD 8-bit footage off a handycam that you're going to put on youtube. I suggest a tag for these questions:

[NO]

Comment: You have my full support!